# Mysql Table Update Query is very slow and its increasing day by day

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

We have a table which just for the update query it takes almost 200-300 secs, the total data size is almost 3,357,196 rows. We have the keys attached to it and the select query is very fast. Only the update query is taking a lot of time.

Mysql 
Db Engine: InnoDB

```
CREATE TABLE `t_strava_push` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `strava_user` int(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `strava_workout` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `aspect` varchar(45) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `event_time` int(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `body` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `processed` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_UNIQUE` (`id`),
  KEY `strava_user` (`strava_user`),
  KEY `strava_workout` (`strava_workout`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3377747 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
```

The query we are trying to update :

```
UPDATE t_strava_push SET processed = 3 WHERE strava_workout = 2677850786
```

The table is being constantly updated by a cron job which runs every 2 minutes. And a lot of data is coming to the table every minute.

[Check the MySQL profiling here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbmQD.png)

[Table Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcMfp.png)

[Check the process which are running in that table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rikF.png)

Comment: I removed the `sql-server` tag; since this question is apparently related to `mysql` only.

Comment: Incidentally, the numbers in parentheses after the INT keyword are fairly meaningless. And, seeing as strava_workout is a string, that should really be `'2677850786'`. Oh, and your UNIQUE KEY definition is redundant

Comment: Could you explain more? @Strawberry

Comment: More about what?

Comment: why my UNIQUE KEY definition is redundant ? @Strawberry

Comment: Because a PRIMARY KEY is, by definition, UNIQUE

Comment: My advice: change `strava_workout` field type to integer (if it possible). This will reduce table size, index size and can improve update performance.

Comment: If you add `EXPLAIN` in front of your SQL statement you can see the query plan and better understand how mySQL is processing the statement, whether any indexes are being used etc.
As a rule of thumb, if none of the fields used as criteria have indexes, then mySQL has to do a full table scan to determine which rows to update. The more the table grows, the slower the update is going to be over time. Couldn't you perform the UPDATE based on another field like ID for example ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`strava_workout` is a string.  But you are comparing it as a number, so the index is not being used.

Keep the types consistent!

```
UPDATE t_strava_push
    SET processed = 3
    WHERE strava_workout = '2677850786';
```

Comment: @Adhip R - I agree with the answer given by Gordon Linoff, but I'm interested to know if your results confirmed that. If so please mark it as the answer (Gordon Linoff), or whether there was still a problem.

Comment: Yes, this was the issue for me thanks @gordon Linoff